# How to simulate camera turbulence for in-game cinematics

Tags: 3d, algorithm, camera, simulations, cutscene

Are there any good algorithms for generating a convincing turbulence effect that can be applied to an in-game camera.

For example, in use cases such as the viewpoint of a plane flying low and fast over a landscape.

Comment: How do you imagine the turbulence effects are perceived in the cinematic sequence? Do you want the camera to randomly stray-off as if it were attached to a plane experiencing irregular air-streams along its trajectory? Do you maybe want to affect the rendered image (at texture/pixel level) by squeezing or stretching it to make the effect more dramatic as if the shunts and bumps contribute to it by distorting the image itself? There are many options, you should start by defining what the effect itself is to be perceived by. Or is that part of your question too?

Comment: I'd say that that's part of the question too. If there are a number of different approaches, then it would be interesting to find out about them. Essentially, I want to add to the sense of drama, and speed, but avoiding looking fake.

Comment: Well, then if you also want some drama, there are some tricks you can employ without distorting the frame of your video after it has been rendered (i.e. in a pixel shader). That can be achieved by adding a noisy displacement to your camera by using a Perlin noise map (which is continuous noise and does not seem unnatural). You can also add some springiness to your camera (as if it is attached via springs to your object of interest). Also, altering the FOV slightly can add to the drama. So can tampering with the depth of field blur parameters. Depends on what system you have available, really.

Comment: For speed a common practise is to slightly adjust the camera's fov based on speed input.

Comment: By "pixel shader" distortion I mean something on these lines: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4sfGRH (not everything in that shader is relevant! Only the slight distortions that affect the "CPU" word can be of help. Note that such distortions are specific to mechanical cameras and even to our eye. When the camera/eye experiences a shock from a turbulence, the lenses wiggle slightly and thus distort the image, producing a "blobby/underwater" perception for a few instances of a second. If you want to convey this effect, then you'll have to use such a shader as well).

Comment: Do you have sample footage (even if it's real life & not from a game) of what you would like to achieve? It's easier to solve a problem if you/we have a sense of what a correct solution looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might just want a basic camera shake.

```
// Maximum offset of shake, per axis. Keep this small - millimetres usually.
Vector3 max_amplitudes;

// Number of oscillations per second, per axis. 
// Keep this lower than half your framerate to avoid temporal aliasing.
Vector3 frequencies;

Vector3 ShakePosition( Vector3 unshakenPosition, float trauma ) {
   // Making amplitude proportional to the square or cube of the input trauma
   // helps give a gentler ramp-out to the shake, and clearly distinguishes intensities.
   Vector3 amplitude = max_amplitudes * trauma * trauma * trauma;
   Vector3 phases = time * frequencies;

   Vector3 offset;
   // Using trig functions gives a periodic shake, like the camera's mount
   // has a little wobble in it like a stiff spring. Using different frequencies
   // on each axis helps the shake look chaotic instead of repetitive.
   offset.x = cos(phases.x) * amplitude.x;
   offset.y = cos(phases.y) * amplitude.y;
   offset.z = cos(phases.z) * amplitude.z;

   // You can use your favourite continuous noise function instead of cos if you like,
   // eg. Perlin noise with different frequencies / offsets per axis.

   return unshakenPosition + offset;
}

// You can incorporate this into your camera update something like this...
void UpdateCamera() {
    camera.unshakenPosition = UpdateCameraPosition(camera.unshakenPosition);

    // You can also track & decay trauma frame-to-frame, 
    // to layer speed-based rumble with spiky shakes due to impacts.
    float trauma = speed / max_speed;

    camera.shakenPosition = ShakePosition(camera.unshakenPosition, trauma);

    // Note that we keep the shaken and unshaken positions separate.
    // We always update camera behaviour using the unshaken position,
    // and use the shaken position for final rendering only.
    // This keeps the shake from exploding in a feedback loop,
    // or interfering chaotically with carefully-tuned gameplay behaviours.
}
```

This models small vibrations of the camera mount and airframe. Try that and see how it feels. If you need more complexity, you can use this same template to add more layers like...

- Rotational shake - same idea, but shake in local Euler angles instead of xyz position
- Gusts & air pockets - add a second shake with a bigger max amplitude on a lower frequency (you can even apply this fractally, but two layers is probably enough)